# Metric to quantify randomness

Tags: monte-carlo, information-theory, metric, randomness, spatial-correlation

I have an $L \times L$ matrix representing a $2D$ region. Each entry of this matrix is a real number lying in the closed interval [0,1]. I want to quantify how different is this from a similar $L \times L$ matrix with completely random entries (say when each entry is sampled independently from a continuous uniform
distribution between $[0,1]$).

A naive way I can immediately think of is to use Monte Carlo methods - Sample a random matrix as described above and use the difference of
matrix norms (e.g. Frobenius norm, L2 norm) as the metric. This can be averaged over say 50,000  such iterations to get a measure of how
different the matrix is from a completely random one.

Is there a more principled metric which can be used to compare such
matrices based on how different they are from a random matrix? I feel a more information-theoretic approach that measures the "informational content" of the matrix in Shannon's sense will be relevant here.

Also, need we define the random matrix in a different way (perhaps to
make it easier to compute this metric)?

**Context** - The entries of the matrix represent the population of the region (which has been discretized into grid cells). I want to study how population changes in each cell over time. I want to be able to quantify how complex is this evolution of the population (for example, if one can identify some complex behavior representative of a complex system).
Note that it is important to compare matrices as such (and not flatten them to 1D arrays) because adjacent cells in the matrix are spatially correlated and by flattening we will lose this crucial information

Comment: There are infinitely many possible metrics. Perhaps the first issue to address is why you would want to compare a binary matrix to one with arbitrary real values between $0$ and $1.$  The very next issue would be what such a random matrix might represent.  What is the problem you actually need to solve?

Comment: Re the edit: it sounds like you are looking for a spatio-temporal model.  This is an extremely complex subject.  It's unlikely you will make significant advances merely by comparing matrices somehow.  A good approach begins by formulating a quantitative model of how the system might evolve.

Comment: Yes, I am exploring those directions as well. For this question though, I am just curious to know if there is a metric to quantify, at any point in time, how much more the matrix is informative w.r.t an arbitrarily random matrix.

Comment: An approach I can think of is to construct an LxL matrix with each entry as 0.5 (mean of the uniform distribution over [0,1]). Then subtract this from our matrix, and a norm of this resultant matrix can be used as our metric. Can there be a more intelligent approach according to Information Theory? Also @whuber is this what you meant by saying "there are infinitely many possible metrics"?